# Java define generic in the constructor

Tags: java, generics

Is there way to define generic in the class in the constructor? So it looks something like this:

```
class Foo {
    public Foo (boolean b){
        if (b) Foo = <Integer>;
        else Foo = <Double>;
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is more complicated and defining generic in the constructor would be best option for me. If it is impossible, what would be closest work around to it?

Comment: Why would you do that?  Can't you just make an ordinary generic class, and write `new Foo<Integer>()` or `new Foo<Double>()` to instantiate it, instead of `new Foo(true)` or `new Foo(false)`?  Wouldn't that have the effect that you're looking for?  If the `boolean` is a variable when you're instantiating the class, you could write something like `Foo<?> foo = condition ? new Foo<Integer>() : new Foo<Double>();`

Comment: @DavidWallace I would do that because I need the generic to be one and only one of the types (it is a class for a library), which do not extend same class (specifically either Boolean, Integer, Double or SecureInteger(my own written class)). I guess in that cases I will go with private constructor and public static mathod to create it with the code you wrote. Can you post it as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Yeah, I think the private constructor and public static "create" method is probably a good solution.  You could post it as an answer yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is the solution based on David Wallace comment:

```
    class Foo <T> {

        private Foo (){}

        public static Foo<?> createFoo (boolean b){
            return b ? new Foo<Integer>() : new Foo<Double>();
        }
    }
```